# How to backup more than 1 database in once in MYSQL using command line on ubuntu server 10.10?

Tags: mysql, database, backup, ubuntu-10.10

I am backupping some databases, but NOT ALL from my old Computer using ubuntu 10.10 and MySQL installed ofc.
so i go for

```
sudo mysqldump "DBNAME" -u root -p > DBBACKUPNAME.SQL
```

after entering the password, the backup is successfully stored in the dir I am currently in.
Fine.

But now i want to backup more than one DB. I tried

```
sudo mysqldump "DBNAME1,DBNAME2" -u root -p > DBBACKUPNAME.SQL
```

But that's not working.
So How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, using :

```
sudo mysqldump --databases DBNAME1 DBNAME2 -u SQLUSERNAME -p > SQLBACKUP.sql
```